# form_for Custom Rails Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, view-helpers, form-helpers

Here the call in view:

```
<%= f.label form_val(:name) %>
```

Here's the custom helper:

```
def form_val(input)
   if @user.errors[input].blank?
     input
   else
     @user.errors[input].to_sentence
   end
end
```

The above works and if there is a form error the input label will display the validation error. Now I need to add Input: to the beginning of the error and a class at the end.
Thus displaying:

```
<%= f.label :name, 'Name' + @user.errors[:name].to_sentence, class: "some_class" %>
```

I've tried the following as it makes sense, but I'm getting an SyntaxError:

```
def form_val(input)
  if @user.errors[input].blank?
    input
  else
    input, @user.errors[input].to_sentence, class: "some_class"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to return method arguments as a return from a method. Methods can only return one value; be it int, string, or class object. Your syntax error is because it is trying to return 3 values.

What you may want to do is create a helper method for the view or in app/helpers/application_helper.rb. This way you can return the f.label call with the proper arguments as you desire. Something like:

```
def error_helper(input, form)
  if @user.errors[input].blank?
    return form.label(input)
  else
    return form.label(input, @user.errors[input].to_sentence, class: "some_class")
  end
end
```

I like parenthesis in this situation for readability. I am sure this can be written using a better technique but maybe this will get you on the right track?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your example does work but if an input isn't blank it returns the validation error only and not the input + the validation error. It appears as if your example says to return the input, the error to sentence, and the class but it's only returning the final 2.

Comment: Sorry, I copied/pasted your final def code. You probably want to "return form.label(input.to_sym, "#{input.to_s.capitalize}:#{@user.errors[input.to_sym].to_sentence}", class: "some_class")" in the else scope. This would be string interpolation to include :name as string "Name" with a colon to separate into the errors.

Comment: Fantastic sir, thanks a bunch. And I do understand your original observation - the method can only return one value per statement. CHEERS!